# Left-navigation sort

Tags: 2010, navigation, sorting

Although not standard, I have a custom field in each of my pages library in SharePoint 2010. This field is used to select a particular branch/location. The left-navigation is then populated according to that branch.

If I wanted to go one step further, and order the pages in the left nav by branch how could I go about it? These are all requirements, but I am stuck on this last part of sorting.

Any thoughts or Ideas?

Comment: If you do not have developer access, but can add to either the master page or individual pages, you can use javascript/jQuery to sort the elements.

Comment: The issue is pre-determining the order. I have the branch, however I need to specify a specific order of pages for each branch.

Comment: You could just hard code the order for each branch. Not terribly sexy and hard to maintain but it would work. Going one step further, you could store the order in a separate SharePoint list and just pull from that.

Comment: I take it you use a custom developed aspnet control you use as left-navigation in order to make this branch/location selection usable. If this is true, what prevents you from performing the sorting in the control before rendering?

Comment: I did use an aspnet control. The issue is allowing the user to select the order in which they wish items to be disabled. The sorting I can do it in the code.